# Vuetify autocomplete , inner icons changes color when focused

Tags: css, vuetify.js

https://codepen.io/pmulder/pen/qJrgbz

```
<v-autocomplete
  :loading="loading"
  :items="items"
  :search-input.sync="search"
  v-model="select"
  cache-items
  class="mx-3"
  hide-no-data
  hide-details
  label="What state are you from?"
  solo
  prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"          
></v-autocomplete>
```

When clicking on the input field the inner icons changes color ( to blue in this example). Is there a way to control this ?  Keeping it the same color for example.

Comment: Have you looked at the color prop ? [Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#props)

Comment: @BilalAkbar : It was that simple , i thought it would change the input text color as well, but it did not.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the color property. [Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#props)

```
<v-autocomplete
  :loading="loading"
  :items="items"
  :search-input.sync="search"
  v-model="select"
  cache-items
  class="mx-3"
  hide-no-data
  hide-details
  label="What state are you from?"
  solo
  prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
  color="#fff"          
></v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify colors based on your theme with the 'light' and 'dark' prop